# Web Form template vs Web API template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When creating a new web project in Visual Studio 2015, there is a Web Forms template and a Web API template.  I have used only Web Forms projects.  I haven't been able to find a good explanation of the differences between the project types.  What are the differences/advantages between a Web API project and a Web Forms project?

Comment: A web forms project is usually a web site, serving html, css, etc. A web api project is intended to provide just data, usually in the form of json, or to expose actions to clientside software (thing like adding data, deleting data, etc.). I suggest you create one and see what it does. It's more fun to learn by messing around with it.

Comment: So the API is not focused on http services then?  I would use it to support the back end requests from java apps and such that just need data served versus http webpages?

Comment: Yep, that is pretty much it. Web api is used to provide data to clients; those can be websites or mobile apps or whatever. If you're not interested in serving html, just data, go for web api.

Comment: TYVM.  Please post your first comment as an answer so I can give you credit, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web forms project is usually a web site, serving html, css, etc. A web api project is intended to provide just data, usually in the form of json, or to expose actions to client side software (thing like adding data, deleting data, etc).

I suggest you create one and see what it does. It's more fun to learn by messing around with it.